# how to create a chain of processes using fork()?

Tags: c++, c, fork

I'm trying to create 10 processes but not fanned out but rather in a chain. So process 1 is

Comment: won't a for loop create a fan of processes though

Comment: @user3195820: Not if you `fork()` in the newly born child. Just break out of the loop in parent, and let child go to the next iteration.

Comment: oh soo in the do childish things section of the for loop i can fork() to create the new process?

Comment: @user3195820 If you're referring to my answer, it already does that. Only child processes continue on through the next iteration of the `for` loop to `fork` another child process. Parent processes always `break` out.

Comment: Something like `while(fork() == 0 && ++count < 9) {}` assuming the initial process counts as 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is untested:

```
for( int generation = 0 ; generation < 10 ; ++generation )
{
  int pid = fork();
  if( pid != 0 )
  {
     // Do parental things, including wait
     break;
  }
  // Do childish things before forking.
}
```

Each child knows its own `generation`.